# in MDX Where clause does not filter calculated member

Tags: mdx

Why where clause filter works with [All subcategoty] member
and not with [All_Category] member?

```
with member [All_Category] as
    ([Product].[Category].[All Products],[Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount])
member [All_SubCategory] as
    ([Product].[Subcategory].[All Products],[Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount])
select 
    {[All_Category],
    [All_SubCategory],
    [Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount]} on 0
from [Adventure Works]
where [Product].[Category].&[4]
```

Result:

```
All_Categry     All_SubCategry      Reseller Sales Amount

$80,450,596.98  $571,297.93     $571,297.93
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the expression of `[All_Category]` change the current category.

I think `[Product].[Category].[All Products]` and `[Product].[Subcategory].[All Products]` do not belong to the same **hierarchy**.